# Pre filter datasource for Magento 2 custom grid

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, collection, grid

I have 2 grid that i want to use in my custom module, the first grid have actions column that have link to access the second grid, the problem is i want to load data in second grid (listingproduct) based on the first grid primary id which will be send via url like this:

```
                    'lazada' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            'test_lazada/listingproduct/index',
                            [
                                'listing_id' => $item['listing_id']
                            ]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('List')
                    ]
```

it will generated lnk like this:

```
localhost/admin/lime_lazada/listingproduct/index/listing_id/<listing_id>/key/<form_key>
```

the **listing_id** is the primary key i'm gonna use to filter the second grid datasource, here's how i define the datasource for my first grid and second grid in di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- first grid  -->
    <virtualType name="Lime\Lazada\Model\ResourceModel\Listing\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">lime_listing</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Lime\Lazada\Model\ResourceModel\Listing\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="lime_listing_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Lime\Lazada\Model\ResourceModel\Listing\Grid\Collection</item>
                <item name="lime_listingproduct_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Lime\Lazada\Model\ResourceModel\Listingproduct\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <!-- second grid  -->
    <virtualType name="Lime\Lazada\Model\ResourceModel\Listingproduct\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">lime_listingproduct</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Lime\Lazada\Model\ResourceModel\Listingproduct\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

here's my Adminhtml/Listingproduct/Index.php:

```
namespace Lime\Lazada\Controller\Adminhtml\Listingproduct;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__("listingproduct"));
            return $resultPage;
    }
}
```